AWS Managed AD, incorrect URL used by Certificate Template?
I have AWS Managed AD. I created a Certificate Template in Certificate Templates Console, which I reached by:

Open "Run"
Enter "certtmpl.msc"

I right clicked on the existing  Kerberos Authentication template and clicked on Duplicate Template. I then made some slight modifications, based on section 1.2 in this article. Namely,

In General tab, enable Publish certificate in Active Directory
In Request Handling tab, enable Allow private key to be exported
In Subject Name tab, enable DNS name
In Security tab, enable Enroll and Autoenroll for Authenticated Users

Now, when I go to a laptop and obtain the certificate (because it is domain joined), the Certificate Template created above appears:

Open Run
Enter mmc
Add/remove snap in for certificates for local computer
Right click on Personal folder, click on All Tasks, click on Request new certificate, select the certificate template I created above

In step 4, when I click on Enroll, it doesn't finish enrolling, because it says the following:
An error occurred while enrolling for a certificate. The certificate request could not be submitted to the certification authority. Url : servermanager.mywebsite-internal-domain.com. Error : The RPC server is unavailable. 0x800706ba

With AWS Managed AD, I have my 2 domain controllers of course, I then I also have a Windows Server  instance that is domain joined to the domain controllers and acts as a configuration and management instance for the domain controllers.
I realized that the Url used for enrollment is incorrect. The Url being used for the template and enrollment, as listed in the above error message, is to the server manager instance, not the domain controllers.
I tried clicking around to see if I could change the URL but I don't see the option, neither on the client computer requesting the certificate, nor on the server instance and the template settings.
My Question
How can I change the URL that is used by the template for enrolment to not point to the windows server management instance, but rather point to the dual/HA domain controllers?
So for example, instead of the certificate using the enrolment URL servermanager.mywebsite-internal-domain.com, I would want it to use controllers.mywebsite-internal-domain.com, which resolves to 2 IP addresses, which are the IP addresses of the 2 domain controllers in HA.
